# Task Error handling - Visual studio stops

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, visual-studio-2013

so basically I want to test Tasks in c#.

My code is the following:

```
    Task tm = new Task(Test);
    tm.ContinueWith(ExceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    tm.Start();


    void ExceptionHandler(Task task)
    {
        var ex = task.Exception;
        ex.Handle((x) =>
            {
                if(x is PictureNotRecognized)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("An exception occured" + Environment.NewLine + "Program aborted: {0}" + Environment.NewLine + "Step: {1}" + Environment.NewLine + "Error Message: {2}", (x as PictureNotRecognized).Aborted, (x as PictureNotRecognized).CurrentStep, (x as PictureNotRecognized).Message));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }

    void Test()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

So, when I run the application it throws the exception and visual studio stops. only if I press F5 again it continues and jumps to `ExceptionHandler`. How can I deactivate this in Visual studio? it should not break the program if the exception is created by the user with `throw new XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable break of exceptions in Debug -> Exceptions -> Command Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> System.Exception -> Uncheck "User-unhandled".

Except the breaking is only when debugging and the user won't notice the exception break! But Visual Studio notices you  that you didn't handle the exception like a Try Catch construction. For more information about exception handeling with Task's see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx